# Increase of GPU memory usage during training

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I was training the network on usual MNIST dataset, and encountered the next problem:
when i start to add `valid_metrics` to a loss_list and accuracy_list, amount of GPU memory that is being used starts increasing with every 1 or 2 epochs.
This is the code of `train_loop`:

```py
def train_model(model: torch.nn.Module, 
                train_dataset: torch.utils.data.Dataset,
                valid_dataset: torch.utils.data.Dataset,
                loss_function: torch.nn.Module = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(),
                optimizer_class: Type[torch.optim.Optimizer] = torch.optim,
                optimizer_params: Dict = {},
                initial_lr = 0.01,
                lr_scheduler_class: Any = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau,
                lr_scheduler_params: Dict = {},
                batch_size = 64,
                max_epochs = 1000,
                early_stopping_patience = 20):
    
    
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=initial_lr, **optimizer_params)
    lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler_class(optimizer, **lr_scheduler_params)
    
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
    valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

    best_valid_loss = None
    best_epoch = None
    loss_list = list()
    accuracy_list = list()
    
    for epoch in range(max_epochs):
        
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}')
        
        start = timer()
        
        train_single_epoch(model, optimizer, loss_function, train_loader)
        
        valid_metrics = validate_single_epoch(model, loss_function, valid_loader)
        loss_list.append(valid_metrics['loss'])
        accuracy_list.append(valid_metrics['accuracy'])
        
        print('time:', timer() - start)
        print(f'Validation metrics: \n{valid_metrics}')

        lr_scheduler.step(valid_metrics['loss'])
        
        if best_valid_loss is None or best_valid_loss > valid_metrics['loss']:
            print(f'Best model yet, saving')
            best_valid_loss = valid_metrics['loss']
            best_epoch = epoch
            torch.save(model, './best_model.pth')
            
        if epoch - best_epoch > early_stopping_patience:
            print('Early stopping triggered')
            return loss_list, accuracy_list
```

and the code of `validate_single_epoch`:

```py
def validate_single_epoch(model: torch.nn.Module,
                          loss_function: torch.nn.Module, 
                          data_loader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader):
    
    loss_total = 0
    accuracy_total = 0
    
    for data in data_loader:

        X, y = data
        X, y = X.view(-1, 784), y.to(device)
        X = X.to(device)
        
        output = model(X)
        
        loss = loss_function(output, y)
        loss_total += loss
        

        y_pred = output.argmax(dim = 1, keepdim=True).to(device)
        accuracy_total += y_pred.eq(y.view_as(y_pred)).sum().item()
        
    loss_avg = loss_total / len(data_loader.dataset)
    accuracy_avg = 100.0 * accuracy_total / len(data_loader.dataset)
    
    return {'loss' : loss_avg, 'accuracy' : accuracy_avg}
```

I use `GeForce MX250` as GPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely because the gradients are being computed and stored in the validation loop. To solve that, perhaps the easiest way is to wrap the validation call in a `no_grad` context:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    valid_metrics = validate_single_epoch(model, loss_function, valid_loader)
```

If you prefer, you can also decorate the `validate_single_epoch(...)` with `@torch.no_grad()`:

```py
@torch.no_grad()
def validate_single_epoch(...):
    # ...
```

Not related to your problem, but pay attention that you're using a model in training mode during validation, which may not be what you want. Perhaps there is a missing call to `model.eval()` in the validation function.

Comment: If i did everything correctly, this managed to help, thanks a lot  

```python
@torch.no_grad()
def validate_single_epoch(model: torch.nn.Module,
                          loss_function: torch.nn.Module, 
                          data_loader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader):
    
    model.eval() ...
```

Comment: Note that you'll have to change it back to training mode when leaving validation. That is, use `model.train()` after the `valid_metrics = validate_single_epoch(...)` line or right before the `train_single_epoch(...)` if it is not in there already.